# Oracle multi-tenant vs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, oracle-12c

I am from SQL Server background and recently getting my hands dirty with Oracle 12c. I came across few features of Oracle called multi-tenant, Container Database and Pluggbale database. Can somebody tell me what are the direct equivalents of these features in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Why does somebody think this question is not clear? It's clear enough! You need to know both Oracle and SQL Server to answer it. Please don't downvote just because you don't have enough knowledge to answer a question. It's your problem, not the questioner.

Comment: Thanks @Justalearner - The downvoters (without proper knowledge) are prevalent here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can somebody tell me what are the direct equivalents of these features in SQL Server 2012?

An Oracle Pluggable Database is similar to a SQL Server User Database.

Before Oracle 12c an Oracle Instance could only have one Database.  With Oracle 12c Oracle added the ability for a single Instance to manage multiple Databases, like SQL Server has always done.

See [Introduction to the Multitenant Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234) from Oracle Docs.

And [Database Engine Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/database-engine-instances-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) from SQL Docs.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been told:

- Oracle Schemas === MS SQL Server databases
- Oracle Multi-Tenant === N/A

Imagine installing 2+ copies of MS SQL server on the same OS.  This would be like having multiple Oracle HOME locations.  Accounts are not shared and each one fights for HW Resources.

Multi-tenant combines the multiple installations into one.  Each installation being a database you can "plug/unplug" with ease.  These are the Pluggable Databases (PDB).

VM Guests get plugged into a VM Host ; in a similar fashion, PDBs get plugged into a Container Database (CDB).

HW resources can be distributed across the individual database instances (PDB) by the DBA, The VM admin is not needed.

Since the database instance is "virtulized", you can do some interesting things with it.  You can export it and deliver it as a single file.  You can clone Production as QA.  You can clone "golden copy" as "customer 351".

The latter of the two has some interesting capabilities too.  You can have "customer xxx" copies reference the metadata (table design) of "golden copy".  So, when you alter a table in "golden copy", all of its clones will be change too.

I don't think MS SQL Server has anything like multi-tenant.

Comment: "I don't think MS SQL Server has anything like multi-tenant."  Would you say you can "MacGyver" something (using custom ETL/Code from an AG)?

Comment: For the typical DBA/Developer, Oracle Multitenant Architecture does exactly what SQL Server has always done, with some extra black magic and a 36.8% increase in licensing cost over Enterprise Edition.